# how to upload django files as background? Or how to increased file upload?

Tags: django, file, web

I need to increased file upload speed in Django. Any ways to do this? I guess about to upload files as a background, when user send POST request i just redirect them to some page and start uploading files. Any ways to do this? Or do you know any ways to increased upload speed? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Low upload speed could be a result of several *issues*.

1. It is a normal situation and your client doesn't have a possibility to upload at a higher speed.
2. Your server instance using an old HDD and can't write quickly.
3. Your server works on another pool of requests and serves your clients as fast as it could but it is overloaded.
4. Your instance doesn't have free space on the hard drive
5. Your server redirects the file as a stream somewhere else.
6. You've written a not optimized code of the upload handler.
   etc.
7. You don't use a proxy-server that works perfectly with slow clients and when a file is on the proxy server's side give it to Django in a moment.
8. You are trying to upload a very big file.

etc.

Maybe you have more details on how you handle the uploads and your environment.

Comment: If it can help, you can watch my actual nginx config: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69368963/nginx-static-files-doesnt-load-django

Comment: I use ssd server. Just check it out, it have 90% of free space. My django code look something like that: i take request.POST and request.FILES, then write it into database as a file. https://i.imgur.com/qBt5vxf.png

Comment: Hello! Thanks for you answer. I have resource, its the place when people uploading they tracks and we uploading then in musical services. So we need to upload .wav files, they size about 70 - 100 mb for each track. When i uploading track by myself, its takes about 3 minutes for 300 mb, but when people uploading it takes a while if they dont have good connection. My network upload speed is about 700 - 800 mbs, but people who have troubles with that is about 1 - 2 mbs. Can be the problem in my django project? I use nginx and redirect it to django server.

Comment: Your NGINX working with requests from the slow client, and Django knows nothing about it until the full body was uploaded by NGINX. Then the request will be proxied to the downstream. So, I think your Django app will process such files easily - this is a local file in the local OS. Another question is where are your clients and where is your server.

Comment: I see the beginning of the handler, what are the next steps, what you're doing with the files next?

Comment: Next step its sorted and uploading file and other info to database. I guess the problem was because the client from another point of world and hes connection to GER servery is about 0.5 - 0.8 mbs and ping is about 140 - 180

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/exzoBNI.png